# FirebaseUI causes DexException Multiple Dex Files

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI to try out the RecyclerViewAdapter. When I try to run the app the gradle build doesn't succeed and gives these errors:
[Errors shown by Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaxak.png)

This doesn't happen when I take out the FirebaseUI Dependency.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

Edit: I added MultiDex Support as mentioned on [Android Developers Site](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle)

What should I do to make the build successful and run the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code that you enable multidex in your app. If there is problem someone can ensure you

Comment: @Shaon I added the 'multiDexEnabled true' inside of the defaultConfig in build.gradle and added the 'implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'' dependency and added 'android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"' in the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Create a class and extends Application or MultidexApllication. Then override on attachContext function. In your manifest  add this class in your application tag like this... app:name = "className"  plz add manifest code in your questio.  Plz edit it